# How do I detect new SPList is created?

Tags: wss-3.0, alert

So, I have a customized alert template that gets attached to all Document Libraries at the time a particular Site Definition is created.  This is done by a feature that is stapled to the Site Definition when it is activated. This is fine and good.

The problem I have now is that when a new Document Library is created, the feature is not reset, and therefore doesn't swap to the new Alert Template.  How do I capture the creation of the SPList (SPDocumentLibrary) at time of creation.

Comment: "a new Document Library is created" or "capture the creation of the SPList (SPDocumentLibrary) at time of creation"? Depends on it you can use different kinds of event receivers.

Answer (score 5):

The [SPListEventReceiver.ListAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver.listadded.aspx) was introduced in SharePoint 2010 and AFAIK it does not exist for SharePoint 2007.

Maybe you can change your approach and register your event handler to [a list type or a content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475328%28v=office.12%29.aspx).